# Using Vue Plugins

Tags: vuejs2

I’m new to using Vue. I’m trying to wrap my head around plugins. What i’m stuck on is using a component and its method that I add to my plugin:

Component: Rest.vue

```
...
export default {
  name: 'rest',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods: {
      gplFetch: function(query){
    ...
    return ...;
      }
  }
}
...
```

Plugin: global-plugin

```
import Rest from ‘@/components/Rest.vue’

export default {

install(Vue, options) {

    Vue.component(Rest.name, Rest)    

    Vue.mixin({
    created() {
      console.log('rest created');
    }
    })

    Vue.prototype.$gplFetch = function(query){

    return <Access Rest component>.gplFetch(query);
    }
  }
}
```

Using in main.js

```
import GlobalPlugin from '@/plugins/global-plugin.js'

Vue.use(GlobalPlugin);
```

What i’m stuck on is how to access gplFetch in the code above:

```
return <Access Rest component>.gplFetch(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the code work the return should be

```
return Rest.methods.gplFetch(query);
```

But I would suggest taking a different approach and creating a module that contains the `gplFetch` function (or perhaps an API module) and importing that method into both your plugin and the `Rest.vue` component.

**gplFetch.js**

```
export function gplFetch(query){
  // do something with query
}
```

**Rest.vue**

```
import {gplFetch} from "./gplFetch.js"

export default {
  name: 'rest',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    gplFetch
  }
}
```

**global-plugin.js**

```
import {gplFetch} from "./gplFetch.js"

export default {

  install(Vue, options) {

    Vue.component(Rest.name, Rest)    

    Vue.mixin({
    created() {
      console.log('rest created');
    }
    })

    Vue.prototype.$gplFetch = function(query){

      return gplFetch(query);
    }
  }
}
```

This of course, all assumes that `gplFetch` doesn't rely on any data in the `Rest.vue` instance, because if it *does* it won't work from your plugin in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much.  You gave a solution, but you also offered a better solution that I decided to take.  You are awesome :)